# Why in common brouhgt praxis of IT a Quantum Computer is too expensive and not yet usable for business-users?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-circuits, quantum-information, quantum-computer, information

**Why in common brouhgt praxis of IT a Quantum Computer is not yet existent?**
Quantum Computing is a very much discussed term in Theoretical Physics, Information Science and Mathematics, it's a main topic in whole IT Society.

It's a summary for all actual activities with circuits using sub-atomic particles.

Till now - nearly 60 years after first classical computer - we have "Quantum Circuits" which need immense research power only and cost a lot of Money because of necessary error corrections and simulations.

A computer needs clear definable states - in Quantum Physics system knowledge based on probabilities is valid (see f.i. QM Standard Model). We have no usable element like a Relay or Transistor. If we don't have this we never can create any computer system (= set of such searched quantum elements).

So all Quantum Computing till now is science-journalistic writing only - not more. Since the 70th of last century topics arise about a "running Quantum Computer" but in reality all are finaly not usable elctronic cirtcuits of latest micro- and nanoelectronics.

Comment: Quantum computers definitely exist.

Comment: http://www.dwavesys.com/quantum-computing

Comment: Quantum computers arguably exist (they're just not big enough yet...) but D-Wave probably isn't one of them.

Comment: Note that we are *not* a discussion forum. This question seems *primarily opinion-based*.

Comment: Every computer you own runs on quantum mechanics, it just doesn't calculate anything with it.

Comment: Also, quantum information is not only about building quantum computers. It is also about communications (cryptography, etc.) via quantum channels, which has already spawned industrial technology (see the firm idquantique for example).

Comment: Yes they exist, but in very exclusive and expensive research labors only, not in common brought IT-business

Comment: I was working since about 1980 as IT-Specialist. Since about 2000 I started Information Science as following up the experinces of classical computers. Quantum Computing is missing exact and definitiv step by step technology. I suppose we don´t have the fitting instruments to manage confident systems on Quantum Level. We can´t speak of Computers we have experimental Quantum Circuits.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all, the ideas of quantum computing were started in the 1980s, not fifty years ago. Since then, several groups have constructed few-qubit systems and managed to perform multi-qubit operations in a variety of systems: NV centers, trapped ions, NMR, microwave/superconducting circuits...

We just aren't yet at the point where such systems are scalable to many qubits, enough to do something very practical. However, note that it doesn't take very many qubits before you can do something that classical computers simply can't simulate--dealing with 20 qubits starts to get very difficult classically. I know [a professor](http://iontrap.umd.edu/) who says he'll have 20 qubits up and running within the year, so we might start to see some really interesting quantum simulation soon.

Comment: "dealing with 20 qubits starts to get very difficult classically" : yes , but if your goal is to emulate a q-computer , 2 are also too much

Comment: @igael: Why are 2 qubits too much? A system made from two spins is close to trivial to calculate.

Comment: @CuriousOne : it is so trivial that it cannot be emulated perfectly

Comment: @igael: the word "perfect" does not exist in physics. For that you have to go over to the math and philosophy departments.

Comment: @CuriousOne: perfectly means clearly within the same error margin. For your assertion : go to the [advanced search form on arxiv](http://arxiv.org/find) and ask for the word perfect in physics only : 982 in titles and too much for abstracts or contents ...

Comment: Anything with two spins can be calculated analytically. More than that,  a classical computer might be needed but can still get to arbitrary precision.  With twenty or thirty the computational basis starts to get too big to handle even approximately.  That's all I meant.  There's no need to careen off into arguments about what is physics.

Comment: Ok, sure ... but emulation of q-computing means to handle some kind of parallelism, not yet well defined. I'm missing something ?

Comment: No, there's no reason you can't write a classical program that emulated quantum computing to arbitrary precision.  It's just inefficient and scales badly.

Comment: @igael: Congrats, you have found 982 poorly phrased physics papers on arxiv. The proper word to use in physics is "idealized". It has a clearly defined meaning that actually expresses what physicists do. zeldredge is, of course, 100% correct. An idealized two spin system (without coupling to the environment) is numerically quite solvable (and it should be analytically solvable as well). What make quantum computing questionable is the assumption that one can decouple a qc to any necessary degree from the environment.

Comment: @zeldredge : in this case, why one cannot emulate a simple EPR experiment ? outcomes probalistic predictions are not emulation

Comment: @igael I meant that you can computationally work out what would occur. We know what will happen (or can make predictions about) the EPR experiment.  On the other hand a many spin system is still pretty much inaccessible to us theoretically by any means.

Comment: @zeldredge: in this sense, ok ...

Comment: sorry @zeldredge QC is known since 1970... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_quantum_computing